# Connect to SQL server from Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to connect from SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) to Eclipse(Java), but I keep getting this error message:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host localhost, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:6132)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:2609)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2346)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at net.codejava.sql.JavaConnect2SQL.main(JavaConnect2SQL.java:16)
```

The code I do have is:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

//import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;

public class JavaConnect2SQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=students"; // This is where I think the error is
        String user = "sa";
        String password = "123";
        try {
            java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Succesfully connected to Microsoft SQL Server");
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops! There was an error: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
}
```

I think the problem is in the connection URL, but I don't know the host name/instance name. If you can tell me how to get my host name/instance name, that would be appreciated. But if the problem is something else, please tell me!

Edit: I have changed the code, and I'm now getting a different. Here is the new code:

```
package net.codejava.sql;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JavaConnect2SQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String url = " jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-5697KK36:1433;databaseName=students";
        String user= "sa";
        String password = "123";
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection succesful!");
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Here is your error message: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The new error message is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-5697KK36:1433;databaseName=students
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at net.codejava.sql.JavaConnect2SQL.main(JavaConnect2SQL.java:40)
```

I think the problem is that I installed the wrong version of JDBC Driver. My JRE version is 12.0.1. What is the correct JDBC Driver to install.

Comment: Check the sql server jdbc string is in the following format `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE
com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` . If not correct the `host` and `port`  and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in SQL server configuration manager and Microsoft SQL server management studio. The state must be running in server configuration manager and you can try to connect your database in Microsoft SQL server management with your password.
if you connect successfully then there is another problem but it looks like the database is stopped.